# TensorFlow Sigmoid activation function as output layer - value interpretation

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, activation-function

My TensorFlow model has the following structure. It aims to solve a binary classification problem where the labels are either 0 or 1. The output layer uses a sigmoid activation function with 1 output.

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
  ])
  optimizer = 'adam'

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

The output given is an array of dtype=float32 numbers that lie between 0 and 1.

```
array([[9.5879245e-01],
       [3.6847022e-01],
       [3.4174323e-04],
       ...,
       [2.6283860e-03],
       [3.2045375e-04],
       [1.0798702e-03]], dtype=float32)
```

The Tensorflow tutorials state that 
**"Using the sigmoid activation function, this value is a float between 0 and 1 and represents a probability, or confidence level".**
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

My question is:

Do I interpret the float values from output as:

1. "How likely it belongs to the first class label - in this case **class 0 is my first class label**?" e.g. `model.predict()` yields `0.99998` and therefore has a 99% chance of belonging to my first class label (class 0) and 1% belonging to the other class (class 1).

or

2. "The closer the output from `model.predict()` is to `0.0` the more likely it is **class 0** and the closer the output is to `1.0` the more likely it is **class 1**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, value of `model.predict()` function is interpreted as mentioned in option 2.

In order to clarify, let's assume we are talking about spam detection application. Label `0` represents that text/email is not spam and label `1` represents that text/email is spam.

Suppose, after running the function `model.predict()`, we get value `0.9899`. Then we can interpret it as:

- chance of given text/email being spam is 98.99%
- chance of given text/email not being spam is 1.01%

Usually, when we talk about a binary classification problem, we will often use labels `0` & `1` to represent the classes. So the predicted value being closer to `0` means it is more likely to fall under the class `0` (in our example class `0` represents text/email not being spam.). Likewise, if the predicted value being closer to `1` means it is more likely to fall under the class `1` (in our example class `1` represents text/email being spam.)

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer and see if it helps . Somehow I feel that you are getting the predict probability rather than the prediction itself

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002084/how-to-output-a-prediction-in-tensorflow